# Using SFINAE to disable template class member function

Tags: c++, c++14, sfinae

Is it possible to use SFINAE and `std::enable_if` to disable a single member function of a template class?

---

I currently have a code similar to this:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>

class Base {
public:
    virtual int f() { return 0; }
};

template<typename T>
class Derived : public Base {
private:
    T getValue_() { return T(); }

public:
    int f() override {
        assert((std::is_same<T, int>::value));
        T val = getValue_();
        //return val; --> not possible if T not convertible to int
        return *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&val);
    }
};


template<typename T>
class MoreDerived : public Derived<T> {
public:
    int f() override { return 2; }
};


int main() {
    Derived<int> i;
    MoreDerived<std::string> f;
    std::cout << f.f() << " " << i.f() << std::endl;
}
```

Ideally, `Derived<T>::f()` should be disabled if `T != int`. Because `f` is virtual, `Derived<T>::f()` gets generated for any instantiation of `Derived`, even if it is never called.
But the code is used such that `Derived<T>` (with `T != int`) never gets created only as a base class of `MoreDerived<T>`.

So the hack in `Derived<T>::f()` is necessary to make the program compile; the `reinterpret_cast` line never gets executed.

Comment: What about a template specialization for int?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could simply specialize `f` for `int`:

```
template<typename T>
class Derived : public Base {
private:
    T getValue_() { return T(); }

public:
    int f() override {
        return Base::f();
    }
};

template <>
int Derived<int>::f () {
    return getValue_();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

No you can't rule out a member function with SFINAE. You could do it with specialisation of your `Derived` class `f` member function for convertible `T`s to `int` but that would lead to unnecessary duplication of code. In C++17 however you could solve this with use of `if constexpr`:

```
template<typename T> class Derived : public Base {
  T getValue_() { return T(); }
public:
  int f() override {
    if constexpr(std::is_convertible<T, int>::value) return getValue_();
    return Base::f();
  }
};
```

[**Live Demo**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/j1hJ81JX7dCBPZwW)